# Python list Indexing, List[ [x][y]:-z ]

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm somewhat new to Python. I have the following python 2 code:

`m = [1,1,7,7,0,0,0,0,1,6,6,9,7,9,2]
randomDigs = m[6 - [3][0]: -1]`

What is happening inside randomDigs? I get the following output:

`[7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 6, 9, 7, 9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[3][0]` is just a complicated way to write `3` (the first element in the list containing `3` as only element). so your code boils down to `m[3:-1]` which means: create a new list from `m` starting from the 3rd (note: list indices start at 0) element up to (and excluding) the last element.

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/4954037) explains how list indexing and slicing works in great detail.

Comment: Is the 6 not doing anything then?

Comment: `6 - [3][0] == 6 - 3 == 3`: yes, the `6` is 'doing' something.